# Right way to query, Rest api Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, rest

I am using the rest api server by chriskacerguis and i think the way i query is wrong because evertytime i click the links even if i only want id =1 it still shows all the data from my db

Controller

```
 public function users_get(){
   $users = [$this->regusers->get('phar_id')];
   $id=$this->get('phar_id');

    // If the id parameter doesn't exist return all the users

    if ($id === NULL)
    {
        // Check if the users data store contains users (in case the database result returns NULL)
        if ($users)
        {
            // Set the response and exit
            $this->response($users, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // OK (200) being the HTTP response code
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the response and exit
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'No users were found'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
        }
    }

    // Find and return a single record for a particular user.

    $id = (int) $id;

    // Validate the id.
    if ($id <= 0)
    {
        // Invalid id, set the response and exit.
        $this->response(NULL, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); // BAD_REQUEST (400) being the HTTP response code
    }

    // Get the user from the array, using the id as key for retreival.
    // Usually a model is to be used for this.

    $user = NULL;

    if (!empty($users))
    {
        foreach ($users as $key => $value)
        {
            if (isset($value['phar_id']) && $value['phar_id'] === $id)
            {
                $user = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($user))
    {
        $this->set_response($user, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // OK (200) being the HTTP response code
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set_response([
            'status' => FALSE,
            'message' => 'User could not be found'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php
   class Regusers Extends CI_Model{
      public function get(){
         $query = $this->db->get('tblpharmacy');
         return $query->result();
      }
   }
```

Views

```
  <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users'); ?>">Users</a> - defaulting to JSON</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/format/csv'); ?>">Users</a> - get it in CSV</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/id/1'); ?>">User #1</a> - defaulting to JSON  (users/id/1)</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/1'); ?>">User #1</a> - defaulting to JSON  (users/1)</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/id/1.xml'); ?>">User #1</a> - get it in XML (users/id/1.xml)</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/id/1/format/xml'); ?>">User #1</a> - get it in XML (users/id/1/format/xml)</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/id/1?format=xml'); ?>">User #1</a> - get it in XML (users/id/1?format=xml)</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/1.xml'); ?>">User #1</a> - get it in XML (users/1.xml)</li>
        <li><a id="ajax" href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/format/json'); ?>">Users</a> - get it in JSON (AJAX request)</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users.html'); ?>">Users</a> - get it in HTML (users.html)</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users/format/html'); ?>">Users</a> - get it in HTML (users/format/html)</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('api/example/users?format=html'); ?>">Users</a> - get it in HTML (users?format=html)</li>
```